# How to parse such a json array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Im having hard time while trying to parse the following json array. How to parse it. The other answers in web doesn't seem to solve my problem.

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "value": {
    "details": [
      {
        "shipment_ref_no": "32",
        "point_of_contact": {
          "empid": ""
        },
        "products": {
          "0": " Pizza"
        },"status": "2"
      },
      {
        "shipment_ref_no": "VAPL/EXP/46/14-15",
        "point_of_contact": {
          "empid": "60162000009888"
        },
        "products": {
          "0": "MAIZE/CORN STARCH"
        },
        "status": "5"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have to access the values of each of those keys.

Following is my code

```
NSString* pendingResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *jsonData = [pendingResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSArray *argsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[jsonDic objectForKey:@"details"]];
NSDictionary *argsDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[argsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
NSLog(@"keys = %@", jsonDic[@"values"]);
```

Comment: Present the code you've writted

Comment: Why not use a third party library/pod to help you out with the parsing?

Comment: Try replacing your code with the code provided by me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON with Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *pendingResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
NSData *jsonData = [pendingResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSArray *argsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[jsonDic objectForKey:@"details"]];

//argsArray holds objects in form of NSDictionary.
for(NSDictionary *response in argsArray) {
   //String object
    NSLog(@"%@", [response valueForKey:@"shipment_ref_no"]);
   //Dictionary object
    NSLog(@"%@", [[response objectForKey:@"point_of_contact"] valueForKey:@"empid"]);
   //String object
    NSLog(@"%@", [response valueForKey:@"status"]);
   //Dictionary object
    NSLog(@"%@", [[response objectForKey:@"products"] valueForKey:@"0"]);
}
```

I believe you should surely ask your server developer to update the response format.

Also, you can always use Model classes to parse your data. Please check this, [How to convert NSDictionary to custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329793/how-to-convert-nsdictionary-to-custom-object).

And yes, I'm using [this](http://json.parser.online.fr/) site to check my json response.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can parse your whole dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray *details = [[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"value"] objectForKey:@"details"];

    for (NSDictionary *dic in details) {
        NSString *shipmentRefNo = dic[@"shipment_ref_no"];
        NSDictionary *pointOfContact = dic[@"point_of_contact"];
        NSString *empId = pointOfContact[@"empid"];

        NSDictionary *products = dic[@"products"];
        NSString *zero = products[@"0"];
        NSString *status = dic[@"status"];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Following answer is in javascript!**

You can parse your json data with:

```
var array = JSON.parse(data);
```

and then you can get everything like this:

```
var refno = array["value"]["details"][0]["shipment_ref_no"];
```

Comment: `value` is not an array in the example given.

Comment: yes, thanks. But it thought he wanted to know how to do it in javascript so my answer is wrong anyways

Answer (score 1):

you can parse like ...

```
NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSDictionary *dictValue = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[jsonDic objectForKey:@"value"]];

NSArray *arrDetails = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dictValue objectForKey:@"details"]];

for (int i=0; i<arrDetails.count; i++) 
{
    NSDictionary *dictDetails=[arrDetails objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *dictContact = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[dictDetails objectForKey:@"point_of_contact"]];
    NSDictionary *dictProduct = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[dictDetails objectForKey:@"products"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *response = //Your json
NSArray *details = response[@"value"][@"details"]
```

etc. Pretty easy

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as follows. You are trying to read the `details` array from the top level whereas in your data its inside the `value` key. So you should read the value dict and within that read the details array.

```
NSString* pendingResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *jsonData = [pendingResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSDictionary *valueDict = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"value"];
NSArray *argsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[valueDict objectForKey:@"details"]];
NSDictionary *argsDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[argsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
NSLog(@"keys = %@", jsonDic[@"values"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have:

```
NSLog(@"keys = %@", jsonDic[@"values"]);
```

But it should be:

```
NSLog(@"keys = %@", jsonDic[@"value"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is code for parsing JSON array. i have used to parse JSON array from file but you can also do this using response link also.I have provided code for both and are below.

```
// using file
NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:str];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSMutableDictionary *dictValues = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[dict valueForKey:@"value"]];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[dictValues valueForKey:@"details"] copyItems:YES];

NSLog(@"Array Details :- %@",array);

// using url
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.xyz.com"]; // your url
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSMutableDictionary *dictValues = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[dict valueForKey:@"value"]];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[dictValues valueForKey:@"details"] copyItems:YES];

NSLog(@"Array Details :- %@",array);
```